# jquery popup display json

Tags: jquery, yii

I am new babie in jquery,I want display the json in jquery popup but it can not work.

here is my function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".popup").click(function(){   
         var value = $(this).attr("value");
         $.post("/news/index.php?r=news/detail&id="+value,function(data,status){            
            if(data != null){
                $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                     modal: true,                   
                     buttons: {
                     Ok: function() {
                         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                         }
                     }
                });
            }
         });         

    });
});
```

value `data={'title':test,'description':description}`
how can I display "test" and "description" on the popup.
thankyou very much

Comment: where is test and description coming from? you didn't mention this in your code?

Comment: What is the reason for displaying the JSON in a popup? Is it just for testing purposes? If so, you should use `console.log(jsonObject)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out..   Also you would need to include jquery.ui lib in order to use .dialog function.

```
//html
<div id="dialog-message" title="Basic dialog">
    <div id="title"></div>
    <div id="description"></div>
</div>

//javascript
if(data != null){
$('#title').text(data.title);
$('#description').text(data.description);

                $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                     modal: true,                   
                     buttons: {
                     Ok: function() {
                         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                         }
                     }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialog is made in three parts, header, content and footer. You need to get the content element and append the JSON to some child element.

you can configure an open function and grab and element in the dialog/content part:

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
  open: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).find('.ui-dialog-content').text(JSON.stringify(yourObject));
  }
});
```

In this exemple, '$(this)' represent the selector you've use to create the dialog, in this case, it represent the $('#dialog-message') element. So after that you can inspect your dialog and see what content child is and find the specific element you want to add place your JSON object.

see the doc of 'open' method or 'open' event right here http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/dialog/#event-open

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dialog title by setting the "title" property of the `#dialog-message` element. You can set the dialog content by placing text inside the `#dialog-message` element.

```
if (data != null) {
       $("#dialog-message").prop('title', data.title).text(data.description).dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dL8yY/3/)